# Can't Remote Desktop To Hyper-V Server 2012 R2

Tags: hyper-v, rdp, remote, desktop

I enabled RDP, set static IP address, created a local administrator account and made sure remote management was enabled. I can ping the server fine. On the client machine thats running Windows 10 I open up Remote Desktop and type in the IP address and the serverName\localAdmin. When I click connect it loads for a bit and then comes back with the 'Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer' error.

Is there something that I'm missing? None of the devices are on a domain.

Comment: Well, do you have the network properly configured? No word about that from you, as far as I can see.

Comment: Well I have the correct IP, subnet, gateway and DNS server. I can ping the hyper-v server as well.

Comment: Remote management doesn't enable Remote Desktop. Did you enable Remote Desktop in Server Manager? (It's listed right below Remote Management).

Comment: Yes I enabled remote desktop and even allowed the less the secure option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found some info in regards to the issue I was having. Like suggested it is a firewall issue and for future users these are the commands I ran to disable the firewall and then add in some rules afterwards.

Powershell

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "*"
```

Command Prompt

```
C:\ netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Desktop" new enable=yes

C:\ netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Administration" new enable=yes

C:\ netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Windows Firewall Remote Management" new enable=yes

C:\ netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Volume Management" new enable=yes

C:\ netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing sounds to me like a firewall issue.  Check the local firewall on the server you are trying to connect to via RDP.  It will likely need a rule added for TCP 3899.  Another way you could test this would be to temporarily disable the local firewall for the proper profile (Domain, Private, or Public) and try the connection again.  If it works, you know you need to add a firewall exception.  Just make sure to enable the firewall again for the profile you just disabled.

Since there isn't much information about the overall network environment you are working in, make sure there are no other hardware firewalls in between you and the server.

Answer (score 0):

in some systems

you need to execute the below line:

```
netsh firewall set service type=remoteadmin mode=enable
```

before:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Administration" new enable=yes
```